# Why is this jQuery code returning an array instead of a single property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I'm trying to a simple HTML5 mulit-file upload. I'm not trying to use a plugin. My code works, but I don't understand the following javascript :-

Given this html

```
<form action="/convert/files" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload" id="upload" type="file" size="40" multiple /><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="uploadFiles();">Process File(s)</button>
</form>
```

This is how I'm retreiving the file information, in JS...

```
function uploadFiles() {
    var files = $('#upload')[0].files;
    ... snip ...
}
```

#### Questions

- Why do i need to use an array indexer to access the files? ie. `[0]`?
- Why does `$('#upload')` return an array? there's also only ONE item in this returned array.

cheers!

#### Update

Ok - so I'm getting told that it's a `jQuery object`. Ok. So why does this object have an array slot with one item?

[image]

Comment: `$(...)` does not return an array, it returns a jquery object. It does so so that you were able to run some other functions over a matched collection. And it does not make much sense to make an exception for when 1 element is returned, since it's not different from where 0 or 42 elements returned instead.

Comment: ^^^ A jQuery object potentially contains a collection of DOM elements that you access like an array. It's a bit different because they are indexes in an object. Take a look at `console.log($('#upload'));` inside your `uploadFiles()` function. There's quite a bit more than just the numeric indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the jQuery library wraps the functionality of **[`document.querySelectorAll`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)**. It provides an API to work with the results of the query.

`$` is a nice and useful name to use, but remember that it is a function call. I think it is easy to forget that aspect.

When you call the jQuery function with an argument that is a selector (for example, "#upload") it internally decides the best approach to use to match that selector to elements in the document. A new object is created using the jQuery prototype to expose the API. The amount of elements matched is set as the .length of this object. Then the set of elements is iterated (or directly set in the case of using an id). Each element is assigned to a 0 based number index directly correlating to the order the elements were in.

For example, this is the simplified result of an id

```
jQueryReturnObject.length = 1;
jQueryReturnObject[0] = matchedElement;
```

This is the simplified result of multiple elements

```
jQueryReturnObject.length = multipleElements.length;
for(var i = 0; i < multipleElements.length; i++){
 jQueryReturnObject[i] = multipleElements[i];
}
```

In both situations, it appears that there is an array of elements, but really it is simply a facade. There is a length property set, and the indexes are set to give the appearance of an array.

Because the indexes are set, they are accessible from that index. So as you note

```
$('#upload')[0]
```

can be used to access this index. But keep in mind, that what is that index is the HTMLElement you queried for, in other words

```
$('#upload')[0] === document.getElementById('upload') //true
```

The API also exposes a few methods to access that element.

```
$('#upload')[0] === $('#upload').get(0)
$('#upload') === $('#upload').eq(0)
```

And finally, the reason you went through all of that to access .files is because an input typed as file natively has `.files` available.

Answer (score 0):

The way jQuery works, is that any time your user `$()` it returns an array of `jQuery object`s of elements that match.

This is why you can use `$().each()` because it works as an array.

go to your console and paste `$('body')`. You'll see that an array shows up.

While some may argue that a `jQuery object` is not an array, and this is true, it acts a lot like one. It isn't an actual array, but you can do things like `$('body').length` which returns how many elements are found in the object. You can iterate over the object like an array: `for (var i = 0; i < $('body').length; i++)`, and you can grab elements by `index`: `$('body')[0]`. You can even use some array methods: `$('body').slice(0,0)`.

Comment: "it returns an array" --- that is misleading. It's **NOT** an array. "This is why you can use $().each() because it works as an array." --- arrays in JS **DO NOT** implement `.each()` method, so it's misleading and incorrect as well. "You'll see that an array shows up." --- it's not `Array.isArray($('body'))`. To summarize, out of 3/3 statements in your answer 0 is correct.

Comment: In effect it is an array. Of course it's a jQuery object, but it acts like an array.

Comment: It is an object in array's clothing.

Comment: @Brian Noah: "it is an array" --- it is not. "but it acts like an array" --- it is not. It is a jQuery object that has **some** array methods and attributes reimplemented, but it's only a limited **SUBSET**

Comment: "in array's clothing" --- I'm not sure ES5.1 has such terminology as "clothing"

Comment: `$('body').concat(['foo'])` --- according to what you say - this code must work (except it does not)

Comment: Being pedantic over this will only confuse people. 

$('body')[0],
$('body').length,
for (var i = 0; i < $('body').length; i++), all work.

Comment: @Brian Noah: what is confusing is when one spreads something that is not true. If something has `.length` attribute it **DOES NOT** mean it is an array. `var a = { length: 42 };` It's obviously is not an array (but it will "pass" your test)